# Using "entr" to watch files, can I make it re-run the command after *every* file change?

Tags: command-line, file-monitoring, entr

[entr](http://entrproject.org/) seems to only rerun the command for changes that happen *after* the command has finished running. But I use this for rerunning tests after modifying my code. If I make a change to the source while the tests are still running, I really do want entr to run the tests again as soon as the last iteration finishes. Is there a way to make it run for *all* changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upcoming version of `entr` there's a [`-a`](https://bitbucket.org/eradman/entr/src/default/NEWS?fileviewer=file-view-default#NEWS-4) which reruns the utility even if the current utility run has not finished yet.